# How to sort List<T> based on column provided as input

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics, linq-to-sql

I have a generic list e.g:

```
public class Person
{
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string loginId {get;set;}
       public string ContactNo {get;set;}
       public string City {get;set;}
       public string Country {get;set;}  
}
```

After filling the list, I bound the list to Repeater control. In HeaderTemplate of my repeater control I have defined LinkButton as:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <tr>
        <th width="100px">
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" Text="Name"></asp:LinkButton>
        </th>
        <th width="150px">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk2" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="loginId" Text="loginId"></asp:LinkButton>
        </th>
        <th width="100px">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk3" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="City" Text="City"></asp:LinkButton>
         </th>
    </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

When user click any of the link, it fires ItemCommand event. In my ItemCommand method, I check for the command and if its a sort then Sort the list based on the `CommandArgument`.

Here is my command event:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.CommandName == "Sort")
      {
         string str= e.CommandArgument.ToString();
         //var lst=ListPerson.OrderBy(c=>c.[PropertyName from CommandArgument ????]);
         var lst=ListPerson.OrderBy(?????)
       }
   } 
NOTE:ListPerson is my previously populated list of type Person.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you might want dynamic linq.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about dynamic linq?

Comment: try this :  `var propertyName = "loginId";`
 `var property = typeof(Person).GetProperty(propertyName);`
 `var lst = ListPerson.OrderBy(o => property.GetValue(o, null))`

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. I was able to find the solution.